# Error when Installing Sitecore 9.1 on Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, sitecore-install-framework, installation, paas

When trying to install **Sitecore 9.1 on Azure PaaS**, I face the following error:

```
Add-AzureRMAccount : The term 'Add-AzureRMAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At D:\Installing Sitecore 9 in Azure PaaS\DeploySitecore9XPScaled.ps1:15 char:1
+ Add-AzureRMAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-AzureRMAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have no experience with deploying Sitecore in Azure, so I'm kinda lost with this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after investigation, it looks like I need to install Azure RM as a pre-requisite in order to be able to deploy Sitecore to Azure properly.

Just run those two following commands and everything it's gonna be alright.

```
Install-Module AzureRM 
Import-Module AzureRM
```